# Adding data from CSV file to vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, csv, attribute-joins

I am trying to add data from a CSV file to a Vector layer (shapefile). I already created a column with same numbers to have a reference column, so I could join my CSV data to that reference column.

I am actually trying it via Layer properties - Joins but it is only joining 100 rows. It should join about 800 rows. Anybody got an idea how I could solve that?

---

Didnt find the same problem in other topics, only the way to join data via properties that i am already trying to use.
Picture 1 is the table that I want to join to table X.
Picture 2 is the table X.
Picture 3 are the Join-settings.
Picture 4 shows the result that stops at row 100.
[image: Table that i want to join to table X]

[image: Table X]

[image: Join settings]

[image: Result (stops at row 100)]

Comment: Maybe you will need to strip values in the field i.e. delete empty spaces before and after each value.

Comment: Can you explain more detailed what you mean?

Comment: It would be nice if you can share a piece of your data with us. But basically I mean the following circumstances: in one table you have '16/30' and in another one ' 16 / 30 ' or ' 16/30 ' etc. Semantics says they are the same, but Syntax argues that they are different. So, you will get the `NULL` match. To manage this, you have to strip/clean/prepare the data, to get a '16/30' = '16/30' match. Bitte :)

Comment: You are a magician! It almost solved the problem, still 11 rows missing but that could be because of accidently double values in the table. Thanks :)